# I need to get Arrival and departure date record of Italy, do they provide to travelers?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, france, italy, poland

I need a report of arrival and departure, some offices provide this to a traveler ? I was asked by the Canadian immigration office to extend my Permanent Residence Card. Please help me ??  I also need one from France and Poland !

Answer (score 2):

France and Italy doesn't electronically record entries and exits. However, if your passport is not from the EU/EFTA, Andorra, Monaco or San Marino, you should have entry and exit stamps in your passport, which prove the dates.

Poland does record entries and exits if the entry/exit to/from the Schengen Area was through there. However, again, if not from the EU/EFTA, Andorra, Monaco or San Marino, you'll have stamps in your passport.